# Regex for end before optional "--" or \s

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to figure out, how to capture 2 groups from the texts like:

```
---MyValue=4497-DD616-1134-34---\r\n
```

I want to capture the "MyValue" and the "4497-DD616-1134-34". Acceptable any characters, except the \s character (\r, \n, blank space, etc.) and the '-' characters repeated min. 2 times at once.
My current regex:

```
(?<Attribute>[^-\s\r\n]+)=(?<Value>[^-\s\r\n]+)
```

The problem with it is, that from the whole "4497-DD616-1134-34" value it captures only the alpha characters before the first "-" sign. I need to get the whole value before the "--", near the end of the string.
Also, this Regex should work for the strings like:

```
MyValue=17%
Number=72
```

so the "---", "\r", "\n", etc. characters are optional.
I'm using Regex in C#. 
[image: Example, of what is actually captured]

Link to the Regex: [Regex link](https://regex101.com/r/Y4qHt7/1)

Any ideas?

Comment: Show an example of what your expression actually captures.

Comment: `(\w+)=(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)` ? Capture group 1: `MyValue`, Capture group2 : `4497-DD616-1134-34`

Comment: What language are you using? regex come in different flavors

Comment: Edit your question and tags accordingly.

Comment: @Fabien. That does not work for the general case described in the question.

Comment: OP, please provide a link to the regex you are showing in the image.

Comment: @xa19: You can use [`(?<Attribute>[^-\s=]+)=(?<Value>\S+?)(?=---|\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/Y4qHt7/2)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regex like this:

```
(\w+)=(.*?)(?:\s|--)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqPpWk/1)**

On the other hand, if the ending `---` are optional and also you have the literals `\r` and `\n` as optional too, ten you could use this regex:

```
(\w+)=(.*?)(?:\s|--|\\r|\\n)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqPpWk/2)**

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
(?<Attribute>\w+)=(?<Value>(?:(?!-{3})\S)+)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3CAttribute%3E%5Cw%2B%29%3D%28%3F%3CValue%3E%28%3F%3A%28%3F!-%7B3%7D%29%5CS%29%2B%29&i=---MyValue%3D4497-DD616-1134-34---%5Cr%5Cn%20%0D%0A---MyNum%3D72%20%0D%0AMyPercent%3D17%25%20---%20)

Or, if the values only consist of hyphen separated word char sequences optionally ending with `%` you may consider a more verbose regex like:

```
(?<Attribute>\w+)=(?<Value>\w+(?:-\w+)*%?)
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3CAttribute%3E%5Cw%2B%29%3D%28%3F%3CValue%3E%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3A-%5Cw%2B%29*%25%3F%29&i=---MyValue%3D4497-DD616-1134-34---%5Cr%5Cn%20%0D%0A---MyNum%3D72%20%0D%0AMyPercent%3D17%25%20---%20)

[image]

**Details**:

- `(?<Attribute>\w+)` - "Attribute" group: 1 or more word chars
- `=` - a `=` symbol
- `(?<Value>(?:(?!-{3})\S)+)` - "Value" group: matches any non-whitespace char (`\S`) that is not starting a `---` character sequence, 1 or more times.

  OR
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?:-\w+)*`  - zero or more sequences of `-` and 1+ word chars
- `%?`  - an optional `%` symbol.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/fiT0so):

```
var pat = @"(?<Attribute>\w+)=(?<Value>(?:(?!-{3})\S)+)";
var s = "---MyValue=4497-DD616-1134-34---\r\n---MyNum=72 MyPercent=17% --- ";
var res = Regex.Matches(s, pat)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(
        m => m.Groups["Attribute"].Value,
        m => m.Groups["Value"].Value
    );
foreach (var kvp in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}, {1}]", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
[MyValue, 4497-DD616-1134-34]
[MyNum, 72]
[MyPercent, 17%]
```